# query to find no. of present days of employee

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle11g

I am using two servers/database in my application- (1)SQLServer (2)Oracle
In oracle I have a *holiday table* with columns as :

```
**HOLIDAY_ID** - NUMBER(10,0)
**HOLIDAY_NAME** - VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)
**HOLIDAY_DATE** - TIMESTAMP(6)
**DAY_OF_WEEK** - VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
**HOLIDAY_TYPE_ID** - NUMBER
**DELETE_FLAG** - VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
```

using this table I have calculated the number of working/business days,holidays, weekends in a month as follows:

```
PreparedStatement psmnt = conn_pasta.prepareStatement("select payroll_id as payrollId,emp_name_formatted as empName,"
                                + " nvl((select designation_name from designation where designation_id=employee.designation_id),'-') as empDesig,"
                                + " (select count(*) "
                                + " from ( select rownum rnum "
                                + " from all_objects "
                                + " where rownum <= to_date(to_char(last_day(to_date('01-'||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY')),'DD')||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('01-'||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY')+1 ) "
                                + " where to_char( to_date('01-'||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY')+rnum-1, 'DY' ) "
                                + " not in ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )) - (select count(*) from admin_holiday where to_char(holiday_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') like '%-' || '"+currentMonth1+"' || '-' || '"+currentYear+"' || '%' and holiday_type_id=1) workingdays,"                               
                                + " (select count(*) "
                                + " from ( select rownum rnum "
                                + " from all_objects "
                                + " where rownum <= to_date(to_char(last_day(to_date('01-'||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY')),'DD')||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('01-'||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY')+1 ) "
                                + " where to_char( to_date('01-'||'"+currentMonth1+"'||'"+currentYear+"','DD-MM-YYYY')+rnum-1, 'DY' ) "
                                + " in ( 'SAT', 'SUN' )) weekends,"                             
                                + " (select count(*) from admin_holiday where to_char(holiday_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') like '%-' || '"+currentMonth1+"' || '-' || '"+currentYear+"' || '%' and holiday_type_id=1) holidays"                                                      
                                + " from employee where DEL_FLAG=1 order by payrollId");
```

where employee is a table that stores various employee's details, currentMonth1 and currentYear are the values passed from outside

*In SQLServer*
I have an *Attendance table* with columns as:
Date, Status, In, Out, Workhour

Now I have to write a query to find the present days of employees using the 2nd table and data retrieved from first query
What I first tried is that count(workhour) which gives proper output but the problem is it also includes the workhours of the day when employee is present on weekends and holiday. But I want workhours of only workingDays of a month and exclude workhours of weekend/or and holiday if exists

How do I achieve this?

Comment: The present days, do you mean which days the employee is at work, or just how many? Are the attendance data common for all employees? I don't understand what is in this table from the column names alone, please give a couple of example rows and an explanation. Is there one row for each day in the month?

Comment: No, not the days(day-name) but the number of days is required.

Comment: No, not the days(day-name) but the number of days is required. The table names given in database are like year.dbo.month (i.e 2017.dbo.JAN), so for every month there is actually a separate table that stores data of all employees according to their employee_id. The DATE column contains all date values of that specific month(e.g for JANUARY- 01/01/2017 upto 31/01/2017) , STATUS shows present/absent, IN shows inTime of emp and OUT shows outTime of employee and workhour is actually the difference between outTime and inTime

Comment: So in `2017.dbo.JAN`, `dbo` is the employee ID? If this attendance table holds the truth, can’t you just ignore the data from the other database? I’m getting more confused, I think you should explain much better. From the ground up. In the question (you can [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42548571/edit)), not in comments.